# How to insert a GlobalVariable at the end of the module?

Tags: llvm

There's a constructor that seems to match my needs :

```
00055   /// GlobalVariable ctor - If a parent module is specified, the global is
00056   /// automatically inserted into the end of the specified modules global list.
00057   GlobalVariable(Type *Ty, bool isConstant, LinkageTypes Linkage,
00058                  Constant *Initializer = nullptr, const Twine &Name = "",
00059                  ThreadLocalMode = NotThreadLocal, unsigned AddressSpace = 0,
00060                  bool isExternallyInitialized = false);
```

According to the documentation below, if a parent module is specified the gv is inserted at the end of it. How to specifiy the module ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the comment is wrong. You can use [this constructor](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1GlobalVariable.html#a3ef813d6bda7e49e31cb6bf239c4e264), which takes a `Module&` as the first parameter. You can specify a `GlobalVariable` for the new one to be inserted before, but it's optional and without it the new global gets inserted at the end.

Alternatively (going by the title of your question), if you already have a `GlobalVariable`, you can call [`getGlobalList`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Module.html#ad8e80edb2d9d59c473e6fe4918c523d4) on the `Module` and `push_back` your global variable onto it.